# MutableLiveData for collections

Tags: kotlin, collections, mutablelivedata

I request data from server by bunches and store it in the array.To track fetching of the next bunch of the data I have this class.In the `addItems` method I notify `diffObservers` and pass list of new items:

```
class PackItems:MutableLiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>() {
        private var diffObservers=ArrayList<Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>>()
        private var active=false

        fun observeItems(owner: LifecycleOwner, valueObserver:Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>,diffObserver:Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>) {
            super.observe(owner,valueObserver)
            diffObservers.add(diffObserver)
        }

        override fun removeObservers(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            super.removeObservers(owner)
            diffObservers= ArrayList()
        }

        fun addItems(toAdd:List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>) {
            value?.addAll(toAdd)
            if (active)
                for (observer in diffObservers)
                    observer.onChanged(toAdd)
        }

        override fun onActive() {
            super.onActive()
            active=true
        }

        override fun onInactive() {
            super.onInactive()
            active=false
        }
    }
```

The problem is `PackItems` is `MutableLiveData` and it's not good practice to expose it.Is there way to cast it to LiveData?Like usually we do:

```
private val _items = MutableLiveData<List<Int>>()
val items: LiveData<List<Int>> = _items
```

**UPD**:Ideally would be if I could expose completely immutable `LiveData`.But I can't just write

```
private val _packs:PackItems=PackItems()
val packs:LiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>
get()=_packs
```

Because in this case `packs` won't contain `observeItems` method.Therefore there must be custom class derived from `LiveData` like:

```
open class PackItems: LiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>() {
    protected var active=false
    protected var diffObservers = ArrayList<Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>>()

    fun observeItems(owner: LifecycleOwner, valueObserver: Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>, diffObserver: Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>) {
        super.observe(owner,valueObserver)
        diffObservers.add(diffObserver)
    }
   //...
}

class MutablePackItems: PackItems() {
    fun addItems(toAdd:List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>) {
        value?.addAll(toAdd)
        if (active)
            for (observer in diffObservers)
                observer.onChanged(toAdd)
    }
}
```

But in this case I won't be able to set data because now MutablePackItems is LiveData(immutable) :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using composition instead of inheritance:

```
class PackItems() {
    private val mutableData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>()
    val asLiveData: LiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>> get() = mutableData
    ...

    fun observeItems(owner: LifecycleOwner, valueObserver:Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>,diffObserver:Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>) {
        mutableData.observe(owner,valueObserver)
        diffObservers.add(diffObserver)
    }

    fun removeObservers(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        mutableData.removeObservers(owner)
        diffObservers = ArrayList()
    }

    // etc
}
```

EDIT: to set `active` as in your original code, may be a bit nastier:

```
    private val mutableData = object : MutableLiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>() {
        override fun onActive() {
            super.onActive()
            active = true
        }

        override fun onInactive() {
            super.onInactive()
            active = false
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:

> but the main problem is I need to return custom `LiveData` class with custom `observeItems` method

The point is that you don't necessarily. Whenever you'd call `LiveData`'s method (e.g. `observe`), just call `items.asLiveData.observe(...)` instead. If you want to pass it to another method `foo` accepting `LiveData`, call `foo(items.asLiveData)`.

In principle, you *could* modify this approach by extending `LiveData` and delegating all calls to `mutableData`:

```
class PackItems(): LiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>() {
    private val mutableData = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>()
    ...

    fun observeItems(owner: LifecycleOwner, valueObserver:Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>,diffObserver:Observer<List<GetPacksResponse.PackData>>) {
        mutableData.observe(owner,valueObserver)
        diffObservers.add(diffObserver)
    }

    override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: ArrayList<GetPacksResponse.PackData>) {
        mutableData.observe(owner, observer)
    }

    override fun removeObservers(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        mutableData.removeObservers(owner) // not super!
        diffObservers = ArrayList()
    }

    // etc
}
```

but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: composition is a fresh idea but the main problem is I need to return custom `LiveData` class with custom `observeItems` method

Comment: Alexey, I'd like to do in fragment: `model.items.asLiveData.observeItems(...)`.Your approach won't allow this as there is no `observeItems` method in `LiveData`

Comment: And for `observeItems` in particular you just do `model.items.observeItems(...)`, no `asLiveData`.

Comment: oh you're referring `not a good idea` section.Ok I got the idea.Let me try it

Comment: nope.How do I update `mutableData` in this case? If there will be public api to do it then I'd better to give to a fragment `mutableData` itself

Comment: If you want to allow arbitrary updates, yes. I assume not, so you have methods like `addItems`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199437/discussion-between-undefined-and-alexey-romanov).